# Compile time and run time in Perl

Tags: perl, runtime, compile-time

I am reading [this document](http://oreilly.com/catalog/pperl3/chapter/ch18.html) to understand the life cycle of a Perl program.

When do **run** time and when do **compile** time events occur while running a Perl script on a command line like this:

```
perl my_script.pl
```

Comment: do you have a practical question we can help with?

Comment: Consider an example, Say I have a package in package/module.pm. I call a function from this module `foo()` in my perl script `my_script.pl`.  Now if I run this script `perl my_script.pl` when did the **COMPILE** and **RUN** events occurred?

Comment: There is no compilation step in perl, its an interpreted language. The interpreter directly parses and runs your perl code at run time. [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_%28computing%29)

Comment: You are wrong. Perl is compiled, not interpreted. For example, execute `perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e'print "$i\n" for 1..5;'` to see the opcodes for that small program. (These opcodes are then interpreted by a very simple virtual machine.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`perl script.pl` will compile `script.pl` then execute `script.pl`. Similarly, `require Module;` will compile `Module.pm` then execute `Module.pm`.

If the compiler encounters a `BEGIN` block, it will execute the block as soon as the block is compiled. Keep in mind that `use` is a `BEGIN` block consisting of a `require` and possibly a `import`.

For example,

```
# script.pl
use Foo;
my $foo = Foo->new();
$foo->do();
```

Does:

1. Compile `script.pl`

   1. Compile `use Foo;`
   2. Execute `require Foo;`

      1. Compile `Foo.pm`

         1. ...
      2. Execute `Foo.pm`

         1. ...
   3. Execute `import Foo;`
   4. Compile `my $foo = Foo->new();`
   5. Compile `$foo->do();`
2. Execute `script.pl`

   1. Execute `my $foo = Foo->new();`
   2. Execute `$foo->do();`