# iterating over enums in perl

Tags: perl, enums

I am trying to create (automatically) an array every time I create an enum. To do  this I send the desired enum array through a sub (myenum) which first creates an array and then calls enum (via use).

In example below I have two enums, one direct, one with the above method. My method doesn't work :-(  What am I doing wrong?

```
@enumArray=();

sub myenum($)
{
  my @a = split (/\s+/,$_[0]);
  my $prefix = $a[0];
  $prefix =~ s/^://;
  my $len = scalar @a;
  $len--;
  my $i=0;
  for ($i=1;$i<=$len;$i++) {
    push (@enumArray, "$prefix.$a[$i]");  
  }
  use enum (@enumArray);
}

myenum(":THIS a=100 b c");

use enum qw(:THAT a=999 b c);

print THISa . " " . THISb . " " . THISc . "\n";
print THATa . " " . THATb . " " . THATc . "\n";
```

Comment: The `use` happens at compile time, not run time. Also, from a philosophical standpoint, don't you think that a dynamically-assigned _set of constants_ seems odd?

Comment: Oops! you are right. The 'use enum' should not be in the for loop. Fixed the postings. About why am I doing it,  I would like to do a reverse lookup and get the actual string (rather than the number) if i want to print the enum type (like a enum-to-string function)

Comment: Wouldn't a simple hash be sufficient?

Comment: enum will assign values. If I create hashes, I lose that benefit.

Answer (score 1):

`use` performs an action at compile-time. Specifically,

```
use enum qw( :THAT a=999 b c );
```

is equivalent to

```
BEGIN {
   require enum;
   import enum qw( :THAT a=999 b c );
}
```

This is described in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14767671/589924).

This means you want

```
BEGIN {
   require enum;
   import enum split ' ', ':THIS a=100 b c';
}
```

or

```
use enum qw( );
BEGIN { import enum split ' ', ':THIS a=100 b c'; }
```

or

```
use enum qw( );

sub myenum {
   import enum split ' ', $_[0];
}

BEGIN { myenum(':THIS a=100 b c') }
```

I'm assuming the following won't do:

```
use enum split(' ', ':THIS a=100 b c');
```

Answer (score 0):

Investigating further on @ikegami's answer, I think here's one way of getting what you need. This involves creating a new package `myenum` that's a simple wrapper over `enum` which also maintains an array of enums.

`myenum.pm`:

```
package myenum;

use strict;
use warnings;

use enum;

# array with all enums
our @enums;

sub import {
    my $prefix = '';

    # basic parsing like what enum does
    for my $name (@_[1..$#_]) {
        if (substr($name, 0, 1) eq ':') {
            $prefix = substr($name, 1);
            next;
        }
        # add the enums to the array
        push @enums, $prefix . $name;
    }

    # call enum's import() as if it was called from the current caller
    goto &enum::import;
}

1;
```

The main program:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use myenum qw(:THAT a=999 b c);

# this array has the enums
print "@myenum::enums\n";

print THATa . " " . THATb . " " . THATc . "\n";

# output:
#
# THATa=999 THATb THATc
# 999 1000 1001
```

*Note:* This is just mostly skeleton code I wrote as an experiment and you'll surely need to make changes to suit your needs. Especially since in a new edit you've said that you needed to do reverse lookups.

Comment: I will try this one. I haven't had much luck with the BEGIN sub and import combinations..

Comment: sub myenum($)
   {
     #line 1  import enum(split (' ' , $_[0]));
     #line 2  import enum qw(:THIS a=100 b c);
    }
    BEGIN {
      # 1  doesn't work with line 1 or 2 in sub routine
      #myenum(":THIS a=100 b c"); 
      # 2 does not work.
     #my $str = ":THIS a=100 b c";
     #import enum(split (' ' , $str));

     # 3  works
     #use enum qw(:THIS a=100 b c);

     # 4 does not work
     import enum(split (' ' , ":THIS a=100 b c"));
    }
    use enum qw(:THAT a=999 b c);
    print THISa . " " . THISb . " " . THISc . "\n";
    print THATa . " " . THATb . " " . THATc . "\n";